# Installing SciPy 0.11 with pip on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, installation, package, scipy, pip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scipy install on mountain lion failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574604/scipy-install-on-mountain-lion-failing)

Today, I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/) for setting up a development environment. The instructions recommend using the development version (0.11 when the linked article was written) when running Mountain Lion. However, the default pip install is now version 0.11 so I'm guessing this should not be a problem. The install fails on my machine with the following log.

Can anyone suggest a remedy to the problem?

(note, attempting to install the dev version also failed)

```
pip install scipy

> Downloading/unpacking scipy   Running setup.py egg_info for package
> scipy
>     Running from scipy source directory.
>     blas_opt_info:
>       FOUND:
>         extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
>         define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
>         extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
>     
>     lapack_opt_info:
>       FOUND:
>         extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
>         define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
>         extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
>     
>     umfpack_info:
>       libraries umfpack not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
>     amd_info:
>       libraries amd not found in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
>       FOUND:
>         libraries = ['amd']
>         library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>         swig_opts = ['-I/usr/local/include']
>         define_macros = [('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
>         include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
>     
>       FOUND:
>         libraries = ['umfpack', 'amd']
>         library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>         swig_opts = ['-I/usr/local/include', '-I/usr/local/include']
>         define_macros = [('SCIPY_UMFPACK_H', None), ('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
>         include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
>     
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
>       File "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 208, in <module>
>         setup_package()
>       File "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 199, in setup_package
>         configuration=configuration )
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py",
> line 152, in setup
>         config = configuration()
>       File "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 136, in configuration
>         config.add_subpackage('scipy')
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 1002, in add_subpackage
>         caller_level = 2)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 971, in get_subpackage
>         caller_level = caller_level + 1)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
>         config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
>       File "scipy/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
>         config.add_subpackage('special')
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 1002, in add_subpackage
>         caller_level = 2)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 971, in get_subpackage
>         caller_level = caller_level + 1)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
>         config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
>       File "/private/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/scipy/special/setup.py",
> line 54, in configuration
>         extra_info=get_info("npymath")
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 2220, in get_info
>         pkg_info = get_pkg_info(pkgname, dirs)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 2172, in get_pkg_info
>         return read_config(pkgname, dirs)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 390, in read_config
>         v = _read_config_imp(pkg_to_filename(pkgname), dirs)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 326, in _read_config_imp
>         meta, vars, sections, reqs = _read_config(filenames)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 309, in _read_config
>         meta, vars, sections, reqs = parse_config(f, dirs)
>       File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 281, in parse_config
>         raise PkgNotFound("Could not find file(s) %s" % str(filenames))
>     numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config.PkgNotFound: Could not find file(s) ['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini']
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     Running from scipy source directory.
> 
> blas_opt_info:
> 
>   FOUND:
> 
>     extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
> 
>     define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
> 
>     extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
> 
> 
> 
> lapack_opt_info:
> 
>   FOUND:
> 
>     extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
> 
>     define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
> 
>     extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
> 
> 
> 
> umfpack_info:
> 
>   libraries umfpack not found in
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
> 
> amd_info:
> 
>   libraries amd not found in
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
> 
>   FOUND:
> 
>     libraries = ['amd']
> 
>     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
> 
>     swig_opts = ['-I/usr/local/include']
> 
>     define_macros = [('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
> 
>     include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
> 
> 
> 
>   FOUND:
> 
>     libraries = ['umfpack', 'amd']
> 
>     library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
> 
>     swig_opts = ['-I/usr/local/include', '-I/usr/local/include']
> 
>     define_macros = [('SCIPY_UMFPACK_H', None), ('SCIPY_AMD_H', None)]
> 
>     include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
> 
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
> 
>   File
> "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 208, in <module>
> 
>     setup_package()
> 
>   File
> "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 199, in setup_package
> 
>     configuration=configuration )
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py",
> line 152, in setup
> 
>     config = configuration()
> 
>   File
> "/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/setup.py",
> line 136, in configuration
> 
>     config.add_subpackage('scipy')
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 1002, in add_subpackage
> 
>     caller_level = 2)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 971, in get_subpackage
> 
>     caller_level = caller_level + 1)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
> 
>     config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
> 
>   File "scipy/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
> 
>     config.add_subpackage('special')
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 1002, in add_subpackage
> 
>     caller_level = 2)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 971, in get_subpackage
> 
>     caller_level = caller_level + 1)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
> 
>     config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
> 
>   File
> "/private/var/folders/dt/vmqtg5kj26q2vkzrfwg_6hz40000gn/T/pip-build/scipy/scipy/special/setup.py",
> line 54, in configuration
> 
>     extra_info=get_info("npymath")
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 2220, in get_info
> 
>     pkg_info = get_pkg_info(pkgname, dirs)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py",
> line 2172, in get_pkg_info
> 
>     return read_config(pkgname, dirs)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 390, in read_config
> 
>     v = _read_config_imp(pkg_to_filename(pkgname), dirs)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 326, in _read_config_imp
> 
>     meta, vars, sections, reqs = _read_config(filenames)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 309, in _read_config
> 
>     meta, vars, sections, reqs = parse_config(f, dirs)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/npy_pkg_config.py",
> line 281, in parse_config
> 
>     raise PkgNotFound("Could not find file(s) %s" % str(filenames))
> 
> numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config.PkgNotFound: Could not find file(s)
> ['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini']
```

Comment: Just to make sure: you did install NumPy, right?

Comment: Sure did, and tested it. It works fine

Comment: Good. And where is it installed ?

Comment: `>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__file__
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc`

Comment: I seem to be missing the `lib` folder in `blahblahblah/numpy/core`

Comment: Not necessarily, check `np.core.__file__`. But how was NumPy installed?

Comment: `>>> print numpy.core.__file__
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.pyc`

I checked `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/` and did an `ls` and there was no lib folder in there.


Numpy was installed with `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after spending some time, looks like it's a problem between `pip` and `numpy`. This question was addressed [previously on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574604/scipy-install-on-mountain-lion-failing), you could try and see whether the solution proposed (basically, reinstalling numpy) works for you.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see the comments at the bottom of the page in the discussion on http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/